# PHP notice error array to string conversation

Tags: php

Notify error array to string conversation while using these codes

1st code (works but with notice) :

```
   $id=array("PENS", "RINGS");

  try{
   //Database Connection code

  $stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT Name     FROM category WHERE Name IN (:id)' ;
    $stmt->execute(array(
   'id'=> $id 
  )) ;
  print_r($id);

   } 
  catch {}
```

Second code (doesn't shows anything) :

```
$id = implode(",", $id); // return comma     separated string from values of array 

$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Name IN (:id)') ;
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ;
print_r($row);
}
```

What I supposed to do now in order to work with array successfully  in any of these codes?

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);` it's expecting a string (**PDO::PARAM_STR** )and you're giving it an array (`$id=array("PENS", "RINGS");`).

Comment: Same goes to the first one: `$stmt->execute(array('id'=> $id));`, `$id` is still an array.

Comment: `echo` wants a string too.

Comment: Even if it'd be parsed as SQL bound parameters, your query will be like `'SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Name = "PENS", "RINGS"'`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code you are using `echo`, this is problematic because `echo` only outputs strings, therefore it can't convert your array to a string.

In your second code you are using `print_r` which will print the array, but you're using `fetch` which only retrieves the next row from the result set, try using `PDO::FETCHASSOC` instead to return your results in an associative array, which should then be displayed by `print_r`.

Second code:

```
$id = implode(",", $id); // return comma separated string from values of array 

$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Name IN (:id)') ;
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I go for this notice being from the first `$stmt->execute(...` since it comes before `echo`

Comment: @Chris Rowles it's not working, your code doesn't displays anything on the screen...  Although thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error array to string conversion means somewhere you are trying to use the array as string.

`$id` is defined as an array.
you are passing it as a string in this line

```
'id'=> $id
```

Similarly in case of PDO it is expecting a string and array is given

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```